# Validation error besides textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have validation error display besides text box. The value -1, shows error, while the value 0 show alert that the password is correct. The first time user input incorrect password, it display the validation error.

However, the second time it have wrong input, the validation error does not show. I console log the value, it still show the error value(-1) but the validation message doesn't show up. I couldn't see what's wrong with my code.

I'm using if else statement. Does anyone expert could pointed out what might be the cause of this?

```
  var clearFields = function() {
    $('#current_pwd').val('');
    $('#new_pwd').val('');
    $('#retype_pwd').val('');

    $('#current_label').html('');
    $('#new_label').html('');
    $('#retype_label').html('');

    $('#current_label').prop('hidden',true);
    $('#new_label').prop('hidden',true);
    $('#retype_label').prop('hidden',true);
  }
  var changePassword = function () {
    var $result = {};
        $.ajax({
            url: "users/resetpwd",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: $("#changePasswordID").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $result = $.parseJSON(result);
            }
        });
    console.log($result["ret"]);


    if($result["ret"] == -1) {
        $result["ret"] == -1;
        $('#current_label').html($result["curr_msg"]);
        $('#new_label').html($result["new_msg"]);
        $('#retype_label').html($result["ret_msg"]);

        $('#current_label').prop('hidden',false);
        $('#new_label').prop('hidden',false);
        $('#retype_label').prop('hidden',false);
        alert('Password does not match.');          

    } else if($result["ret"] == 0) {

        $('#current_label').prop('hidden',true);
        $('#new_label').prop('hidden',true);
        $('#retype_label').prop('hidden',true);
        alert('Password Changed.');
        clearFields();
     };
  };
```

Comment: check if you are not setting `$result["ret"]` to a string

Comment: I'm not setting it to string. In my controller, I set it like this            $return_ret = -1;

Comment: if possible add fiddle or provide more info.

Comment: @suchit, I have edited some of my code. However, I did not put the code from my controller since I don't think that is where the problem is. I was thinking to reset the value every time the loop end, I put it there, still error. Maybe the clearFields function, but I'm not very sure about that. Thank you in advance

Comment: @suchit the alert('Password does not match.') still occur if the wrong input type more than once, but the validation error didn't. maybe u could help. Thanks

Comment: where is your validation part.

Answer (score 0):

reset the counter to its default value at the start of your validation. Then as the validation runs, it will change the counter -1 or 0 depending on the user input. See if that works.

Comment: I try your advice, still not work. I tried to put alert when error, but that one come out. Still wondering why only the validation wont come out